# Create a login for website and for app with admin

Tags: parse-platform, authentication

I want to create a login system for my app and on my website. It is possible than with the same information to log you on my website or in my app? such as in Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which kind of language you are using to create your authentification form.

- PHP ------> http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php14p1.html
- Ruby on rails -------> https://www.codecademy.com/learn/rails-auth

Hope these sources helped

Comment: it was realy helpfull, but how to create a app of the codes?

Comment: You mean a web application that uses authentification form and has third-party login system like facebook?